# Google Services consumes an excess of data since I moved

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

You know the part of android that checks your email, syncs your calendar and the such? Google Services has murdered my data cap, taking 605 MB of data in four days, two of which were spent with background data restricted and missed emails as a result.

[image]

Is there something wrong with my profile that Android sync keeps trying to fix but cannot? Is it something else? I noticed this started shortly after I moved from Wind in Italy to O2 in Germany.

Comment: I'm not looking for ways to monitor or restrict background data, given that the graph and the switch are _right there._ :-)

Comment: Known issue, see e.g. [here](http://www.google.com/search?q="google+services"+mobile+data). For a possible solution, see [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2383691): It's obviously a bug, either with OTA or Network Location or Google Play.